# Nutzung des Paragrafen-Plurals

Tags: grammatical-number, abbreviation, legal-terminology

*(Da es um die Schreibweise und nicht die juristische Bewertung geht, hier statt bei Law.SE)*

Mit Verweis auf [diese im Internet gefundene Regel](https://www.zaar.uni-muenchen.de/studium/wiss_arbeiten/zitieren/index.html) legt mir jemand als Kurzform von

> Paragraph 123 XY-Gesetz in Verbindung mit Paragraf 234 und Paragraf 345 XY-Gesetz

dies vor, weil es ja eben *nicht* um Vorschriften *verschiedener* Gesetze geht:

> §§ 123 iVm 234, 345 XYG

Wenn man jenen Internetfund als verbindlich und alle Sonderfälle abdeckend akzeptiert, mag man das akzeptieren. Für mich sieht das aber komisch aus, weil es sich wegen des "iVm" (statt "," oder "und") nicht um eine Aufzählung handelt.
Nach meinem Gefühl wäre der Teil vor und nach "iVm" jeweils getrennt zu zählen, also etwa

> § 123 iVm §§ 234, 345 XYG

Es fällt mir auch schwer, das ganze als "**die** Paragraphen 123 in Verbindung mit ..." statt "**der** Paragraph in Vermindung mit **den** ..." auszusprechen.

Sehe ich das falsch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich sehe das prinzipiell genauso. Ein Paragraph ist mit „§“, zwei oder mehrere Paragraphen sind mit „§§“ zu zitieren: (Alle Beispiele entstammen dem geltenden österreichischen Recht.)

> § 16 Abs 1 Z 6 lit c EStG … wenn die Tat nicht nach den §§ 223, 224, 225 oder 230 StGB mit Strafe bedroht ist. (Auch möglich: „§§ 223-225 oder § 230“)

Auch wenn das Gesetz dasselbe bleibt, braucht jeder Paragraph prinzipiell ein eigenes § Zeichen:

> … ergibt sich aus § 1 Absatz 1 **in Verbindung** mit § 4 Absatz 1 Ziffer 3 …

§§ bezieht sich (nur) auf alle unmittelbar folgenden Paragraphen:

> … Verbrechen im Sinne der §§ 321 bis 321f sowie § 321k …

Sobald die Ziffernfolge unterbrochen wird, braucht man ein neues §-Zechen:

> … sind die in § 2 Abs. 1 **in Verbindung** mit § 3 Abs. 1b und 1c bezeichneten Daten … Ausnahmen gemäß § 47a Abs. 3 **und** § 57 Abs. 2 …

Selbst die von Dir zitierte Quelle schreibt übrigens, dass „[m]ehrere Vorschriften ein und desselben Gesetzes“ durch den Paragraphen-Plural zusammengefasst werden **können** – nicht müssen.

**tl;dr** Ich würde Dein Beispiel ebenfalls als `§ 123 iVm §§ 234 u. 345 XYG` schreiben.